# Is there a simple communication/message passing interface between two or more Android Devices?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm planning a simulation that calls for multiple communicating android virtual devices; is there a simple way to get two or more Android Virtual Devices to talk to each other? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

there are several Walkie-Talkie applications for the droid platform, many of which use only the wifi capacities in the android.

For instance :

Zello Walkie-Talkie , Voxer Walkie-Talkie

do a google search. construction workers love them because hte can talk to each other directly on a site that is out of cell range

Comment: Links to these products would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

There is the [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html) project, but that is cloud to device, not device to device (as advertised anyway, I'm sure it couldn't be subverted for other use cases).

You can use text messages, and intercept them before they are passed to the messaging app. that could cost the user money.

You can use the amazon AWS [SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) (simple notification service). There is an android SDK (as well as lots of other platforms). It's not free, but it's very, very cheap.

You could put your own messaging server in the cloud. Easy to write a simple prototype, not so easy to write a secure, scalable solution (which is another reason to look a SNS).

Comment: For anyone else looking for the same thing; you can set up socket communication and do redirections. More instructions on the android developer; search for "network redirections". Alternatively, you can send text messages. The number of each device corresponds to the port number it is attached to.

Answer (score 0):

There are also similar apps for 4G platforms. Contrary to popular misinformation (from may supposed experts who need to read up). In fact wimax and other 4G hand sets have a far better range for this (all alone out of tower range). They are far more powerful devices on EM levels produced.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rebelvox.voxer&hl=en

4gwirelessforum.com/4g.../4g-walkie-talkie-nets-for-first-responders/

I expect the equivalent of "note passing" software for 'not so instant' messages..,that uses cooperative routing on 4G (ie, mesh networks) in software apps for 4G phones in the future. Imagine sending a message for free just by shoving it down a series of hops via the phones on interstate 5 (and possibly hitting a free hotspot at some point)